# Filter ListView with a EditText doesnt work Android

Tags: android, android-listview, android-edittext

In my program I'm trying to search some contacts in a `ListView` searching by a `EditText`.
The code is:

```
private ArrayList<String> listContacts=new ArrayList<String>();
private ArrayList<String> sortContacts;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.myprofile_layout);


    listViewContacts = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewContacts);
    editTextSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextSearch);
    listContacts.add("User1");
    listContacts.add("Albert");
    listContacts.add("lol");
    listContacts.add("str");
    sortContacts = listContacts;
editTextSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                    int count) {
                sortContacts.clear();
                for (int i = 0; i < listContacts.size(); i++) {

                    if(editTextSearch.getText().length() <= listContacts.get(i).length()){
                        if(listContacts.get(i).toLowerCase().contains(editTextSearch.getText().toString().toLowerCase()))
                        {
                            sortContacts.add(listContacts.get(i));
                        }
                    }
                }

                updateAdapter();

            }
```

The program doesn't work: inserting a character the `ListView` erasing.
By debug, i see that the `listContacts` list is **empty** `(size()=0)`. Any ideas?

Comment: Where is your Adapter? and where is the ListView?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace:

```
sortContacts = listContacts;
```

with:

```
sortContacts.addAll(listContacts);
```

As you can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15292980/java-arraylist-pass-by-reference), when you use `sortContacts.clear();`, you are clearing both lists (`sortContacts` & `listContacts`) because of line `sortContacts = listContacts;`

An also, as mentioned in Rajitha comment, unless you set the adapters of your `ListView` in `updateAdapter()` (which I cannot see), your `ListView` will not be updated with the changes of the `ArrayList`s

Answer (score 0):

This is not the recommended way to **filter** a listView's **adapter** .

You are supposed to make the adapter implement **Filterable** and use something like:

```
mAdapter.getFilter().filter(queryText);
```

Please watch google's lecture "[the world of listView](http://www.google.com/events/io/2010/sessions/world-of-listview-android.html)" for more details, including the advantages of using this method.